# How to find the perimeter of a triangle with circular ends?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

How to find the perimeter of a triangle with circular ends?

[image]

I am stumped for this and would appreciate help

Comment: The curved parts all sum to the circumference of one of the circles, and each straight part is a diameter of a circle.

Comment: Hint: what is the angle between tangency points ? deduce curved length is $3\times\cdots$. Then compare the flat legnth to how many times a radius ?

Comment: The height of the three circles is a $2+\sqrt3$ times the radius of a single circle (equilateral triangle + diameter).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

From the following picture we have that

- $R+2R\frac{\sqrt 3}2+R=2$

[image]